# How to iterate over a STL map (find all possible pairs)

Tags: c++, dictionary

How to iterate over a STL map in order to confront all elements. In other words, I want to find all possible pairs. I want an efficient algorithm (complexity).

If have a STL vector, the algorithm is simple.

```
vector<int> vInt;
vector<pair<int, int> > vPair;
for(int i = 0; i < vInt.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < vInt.size(); j++) {
        vPair.push_back(make_pair(vInt[i], vInt[j]));
    }
}
```

However, if you have a STL map as is algorithm?

Obs: I want all possible combinations the values of map (not keys)

```
map<int, int> map;
vector<pair<int, int> > vPair;
???
```

I thought of convert to STL map in STL vector, however I would an approach using only the STL map

Comment: By definition the number of pairs in a map is n*(n-1)/2 for a map of size n. Therefore there is no more efficient algorithm than the one you have for vectors.

Comment: all possible combinations of pairs or keys or values of map ?

Comment: I thought of convert to STL map in STL vector, however I would an approach using only the STL map

Answer (score 2):

*"I want all possible combinations the values of map (not keys)"*

I'm not sure about what you want, but if you want to do exactly as what you have done for vector in your example, on the "values" of map

You can do it like following :

```
std::map<int, int> map;
std::map<int,int>::iterator i,j,end=m.end();  
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > vpair;
end--;
for(i=m.begin();i!=end;++i)
{
    j=i;
    j++;
    for(;j!=m.end();++j)
        vpair.push_back(std::make_pair(i->second,j->second));
 }
```

Comment: I would use `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Naszta yeah sure, the idea was only to show how its possible

Answer (score 2):

You can use `j = std::next(i)` to implement `j = i + 1`, then the code is almost the same as the vector case:

```
std::map<int, int> map;
vector<pair<int, int>> vPair;
for (auto i = map.begin(); i != map.end(); i++) {
  for (auto j = std::next(i); j != map.end(); j++) {
    vPair.push_back(std::make_pair(i->second, j->second));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple a map has begin and end iterators just like a vector so you can just do this.

```
#include <map>                                                                     
int main()                                                                         
{                                                                                  
    std::map<int,int> map;                                                         
    for (auto p : map) {                                                           
        auto f = p.first;                                                          
        auto s = p.second;                                                         
    }                                                                              
    return 0;                                                                      
}
```

Even an `std::unordered_map` has begin and end iterators but it does not preserve order like a map.

It's unclear from your question if you want the Cartesian product of the numbers in your vector, all I can say is if that is what you want your original approach is a better idea than using a map.

Comment: Perhaps OP needs all possible combination of elements inside map

Comment: @P0W clearly if he wants a cartesian product he should not be using a map

Comment: The system already has STL map, can not modify. I thought of convert to STL map in STL vector, however I would an approach using only the STL map

Answer (score 0):

Use `begin()` and `end()`, both to iterate all elements of a `vector` and a `map`.

```
for (std::map<int, int>::iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first << "  => " << it->second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach.

```
map<int, int> m;
m[1] = 1;
m[2] = 2;
m[3] = 3;
m[4] = 4;
map<int, int>::iterator itr1;
for(itr1 = m.begin(); itr1 != m.end(); ++itr1) {
    map<int, int>::iterator itr2 = itr1;
    for(++itr2; itr2 != m.end(); ++itr2) {
        cout << m[itr1->second] << " : " << m[itr2->second] << endl;
    }
}
```